# Scope propagation with Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, scope, cdi, guice

I have a class from which instances should be created (and destroyed) per request (dbSession in my example) and some other classes that use instances of the per request object. Like this:

```
webservice --> repository --> dao --> dbSession
```

(--> means uses)

But then I have a similar use case but the dbsession shouldn't be bound to a request. Like this:

```
webservice --> otherService --> repository --> dao --> dbSession
```

At the moment the dbSession class is bound to a request. To implement the other use case the db session must not be request bound. I could use qualifiers to do so, but then I have to duplicate a bunch (of needed) provider methods for both scopes.

So, I'm looking for another solution. Would it be possible to propagate scopes? I mean that dependencies get injected with objects of the scope of the injection target?

```
@request webservice --> @myScope otherService --> @myScope repository --> @myScope dao --> @myScope dbSession
```

In the example all dependencies of otherService should be in the same scope as otherService (the call to otherService is async).

Is something like this possible with Guice? And just out of curiosity: would it be possible with CDI?

Comment: Looks like a case of the robot legs problem: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-do-i-build-two-similar-but-slightly-different-trees-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

Am I understand it correctly?

First case:

```
@Request webservice --> @Singleton repository --> @Singleton dao --> @Request dbSession
```

What you are looking for in second case:

```
@request webservice --> @myScope/@Singleton otherService --> @myScope/@Singleton repository --> @myScope/@Singleton dao --> @myScope/@noscope_session_per_query dbSession
```

I would suggest you to encapsulate your repository to `PrivateModule` and `expose` only `repository` and `otherService` interface. Then bind in both modules `dbSession` (it means `EntityManager` is supposed?) provider in different scope. Do not forget to use `Provider<T>` instead of direct injecting when you start to mix scopes.

Second option is to use annotation for dbSession/EntityManager providers binding and inject it with proper annotation.